# ESP8266 constantly resetting, but blink script works

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Hello I have been using the Wemos D1 mini lite for awhile now with this ArduCAM setup. Everything was working perfectly, but now my esp8266 is constantly resetting.

I unplugged the ArduCAM and saw I can ran the blink script successfully, but when I try to run a script where it attempts to connect to wifi, it constantly resets.

Here is my code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>        // Include the Wi-Fi library

const char* ssid     = "ssid";         // The SSID (name) of the Wi-Fi network you want to connect to
const char* password = "";     // The password of the Wi-Fi network

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);         // Start the Serial communication to send messages to the computer
  delay(10);
  Serial.println('\n');

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);             // Connect to the network
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(ssid); Serial.println(" ...");

  int i = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { // Wait for the Wi-Fi to connect
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(++i); Serial.print(' ');
  }

  Serial.println('\n');
  Serial.println("Connection established!");  
  Serial.print("IP address:\t");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());         // Send the IP address of the ESP8266 to the computer
}

void loop() { }
```

When I run this, I get the following:

```
load 0x4010f000, len 1392, room 16 
tail 0
chksum 0xd0
csum 0xd0
v3d128e5c
~ld

Exception (3):
epc1=0x40100710 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x4006e989 depc=0x00000000

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffb90 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 01a0
3ffffd30:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffd40:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe 3ffffef0  
3ffffd50:  0000049c 0000049c 00000020 40100900  
3ffffd60:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffd70:  00000002 400042db 000000fd 40100b58  
3ffffd80:  40004b31 00001000 000000fd 40100274  
3ffffd90:  40105ae0 feefeffe feefeffe 4022da8d  
3ffffda0:  40105c9d 4022db77 3ffef25c 0000049c  
3ffffdb0:  000000fd 3ffffef0 3ffef25c 4022db5a  
3ffffdc0:  ffffff00 55aa55aa 0000000e 00000020  
3ffffdd0:  00000020 00000078 00000012 aa55aa55  
3ffffde0:  000000ff 4022e05a 3ffef25c 3ffef25c  
3ffffdf0:  000000ff 00000119 00000119 40100640  
3ffffe00:  40105c9d 00000001 3ffef26c 4022e27a  
3ffffe10:  00000005 3ffef25c 000000ff 3ffffef0  
3ffffe20:  3fffff10 3ffef293 0000000e 00000020  
3ffffe30:  3ffef31c 3fffff51 00000001 4022e32a  
3ffffe40:  3ffffef0 40239860 00000000 00000000  
3ffffe50:  3ffef65c 3fffff10 3fff5594 4022e2f9  
3ffffe60:  3ffef25c 4022e360 3ffe84d4 3ffe8642  
3ffffe70:  40201946 3ffe8642 3ffe8663 4020189b  
3ffffe80:  76696e55 69737265 6f207974 61572066  
3ffffe90:  6e696873 6e6f7467 3ffffe00 40204cbc  
3ffffea0:  3ffee400 00000000 3ffffe60 40204ef9  
3ffffeb0:  00000f98 000001f3 000001f3 40100640  
3ffffec0:  000006e8 000000dd 00000014 3ffeebc4  
3ffffed0:  007a1200 44e0a632 00000000 401008cb  
3ffffee0:  adb5c801 fe20b34c feefeffe 00000100  
3ffffef0:  76696e55 69737265 6f207974 61572066  
3fffff00:  6e696873 6e6f7467 feefef00 feefeffe  
3fffff10:  40203500 3ffeefcc 3ffeef4c 402035af  
3fffff20:  0000001c 0001c200 00000000 00000000  
3fffff30:  00000003 40203771 ffffffff 00000001  
3fffff40:  40105065 00000001 3ffee35c 3ffee3d4  
3fffff50:  00000000 00000001 3ffee381 00000000  
3fffff60:  00000004 00000000 3ffee328 00000001  
3fffff70:  0001c200 0000001c 00000000 3ffee3d4  
3fffff80:  3fffdad0 3ffee328 3ffee35c 40201073  
3fffff90:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3fffffa0:  feefeffe 00000000 3ffee394 402024b4  
3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe84f0 40100b8d  
<<<stack<<<
```

over and over and over.

I don't understand what is happening. Did I possibly short it? It couldn't have been the ArduCAM, since this was working fine already.

edit:

I found out that the `Wifi.begin(ssid,password)` command causes the constant reboots. When I remove this, it doesn't reboot. How can I fix this?

Comment: It would be much easier - possible, even - to give you advice on this if you'd share the actual minimal code which causes the problem instead of describing it.

Comment: @romkey Apologies, I added the code.

Comment: Thanks! I was really hoping there'd be an obvious problem, but there's not :) I compiled and ran your code on a D1 Mini with no problem. I'd suggest trying your device with a different power supply in case it's a power issue. Also there was a problem in an old version of the SDK that could cause exception 3 on wifi connect. Can you make sure your Arduino SDK for the ESP8266 is up to date?

Comment: @romkey I will try that later today. The thing is, I'm just using my laptop to power it, like I've been for the past few months. Granted, I had this thing for years...maybe it's broken? Will attempt the SDK later.

Comment: @romkey How can I check if the Arduino sdk is up to date? Is this the Arduino IDE you are referring to? If so, it is up to date.

Comment: Having the IDE up to date is good :) I mean the code that provides the Arduino SDK for the ESP8266. Go to "Tools", then "Board" then "Board Manager" at the top of the list of boards. Look for ESP8266 in the list; there will most likely be an update available, install the update.

Answer (score -1):

I think your main loop is empty. Add while(true) in the main loop function

and it´s better to set the esp in sation mode.

WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

Comment: `while(true) ;`  would cause a watchdog timeout. There's no need to have anything in `loop()` - and it being empty is definitely not causing the reboot.